# Which ruby mysql library supports prepared statements and last id retrival

Tags: mysql, ruby

I started my ruby project with the mysql library, it has prepared statements what I like very much. Then I found out it had no elegant way to get id's of records I have inserted so I switched to the mysql2 library which has this functionality but it does not have prepared statements and I would have to escape all my values before making queries to the database.

So is there a mysql library for ruby that supports prepared statements and retrieving the id of the last inserted record?

Comment: The mysql gem has an `insert_id` method, isn't that what you need?

Comment: You are right, that is it. How could I not have seen it in the docs. Thank you.

Comment: Calling the mysql and mysql2 docs "useless" would be generous :)

Comment: Note that mysql2 is missing prepared statements for a good reason: if you manually escape your values and use Ruby's string interpolation, it's actually faster than using prepared statements.  If you're using Rails you can even use the standard prepared statement syntax and it'll automatically do the escaping.

Comment: I guess it's OK to write insecure code as long as it's "faster"!

Comment: @histocract: For what it's worth, OWASP [strongly recommends](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input) using prepared statements instead of escaping user input: "this methodology is frail compared to using [prepared statements] and we cannot guarantee it will prevent all SQL Injection in all situations."

Answer (score 0):

The mysql gem (https://github.com/luislavena/mysql-gem) supports server side prepared statements but it's not actively maintained and has been deprecated.

Swift mysql adapter (https://github.com/deepfryed/swift-db-mysql) provides similar functionality but does not have ActiveRecord support.  I'm the author and I actively use it for production applications.
If you need an ORM that supports swift-db-mysql I'd recommend Sequel or a lighter weight Swift Object mapper (https://github.com/shanna/swift)

Hope that helps